# How to remove apps from android market website?

Tags: google-play-store

There are a few apps that even though I uninstalled them (through android market mobile app) still remain present as 'installed' when I go to my website market account (they are not on my phone any more).. I tried installing and removing them again, but it didn't help.. Did anyone have the same problem? Is there a way to fix this so that they don't show up any more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, **Now you CAN remove** the unwanted apps from your market website as well as from the market history. All you have to do is delete from your all apps list.

Goto your play store app and select `My Apps` Then swipe the screen to your left to see the `ALL` apps list.

Just click the crossed circle icon (pointed with the green arrow) to remove the desired app.

[image: ScreenCap]

Make sure you have uninstalled the app before removing. You can uninstall the apps directly from the All apps list as well.

Note: It seems that this list only contains market installed apps. (i.e. apps other than user installed `.apk` apps)

Comment: @pootzko, you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want them removed from the Market app list of previously installed applications, you will have to clear the data in Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> Market.

To get them to not show as installed on the Market website, I would think that this will "clear" once your device does a sync and then the site processes that sync. You have no control over how the website shows applications that are installed. I'd say way a few days and if they are still showing as installed, you can try contacting google about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> ***edit: this answer is outdated, please see [Sid's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/36915/2192)***

I reported this to Android Team, and got this reply:

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for writing in. I understand
>   that some apps are still showing on
>   your account even after being
>   uninstalled.
>
> Keep in mind that all the apps you
>   download will always show on the
>   Android Market website for history
>   purposes. Uninstalled apps will be
>   removed from the Android Market app on
>   your device after a few days.
>
> Regards,
>
> The Android Market Team

So, that means they will never go away from the Android Market website...

Comment: Please see the [new answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/36915/)